# How to run Apple Hardware Test with broken keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, macos, macbook-pro, startup, apple-hardware-test

mid-2011 13" MBA running Yosemite

Coffee spill has left keyboard of mid-2011 13" MBA non-functioning. Even power button doesn't work, I boot by shorting the two solder points on logic board. I've tried to run the AHT with both the broken 'D' and a USB kb 'D'. Neither seems to be registered, as it just boots normally.

Are there any other workarounds for running AHT?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using a USB/bluetooth keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

[You can try to run the AHT from a USB drive.](http://rivenbyfive.blogspot.com/2012/01/download-and-run-apple-hardware-test.html)

see the above link to find/download the AHT for your model.

> 1) Download the AHT for your computer (see downloads below for
>   specific models).
>
> 1b) My copy had me convert the downloaded .dmg from some “old” type
>   using Disk Utility. (Just open the .dmg in Disk Utility and “Convert”
>   to a new target, then mount the target.)
>
> 2) Mount and completely wipe a USB stick.
>
> 3) From the AHT image, copy /System to the root folder of your USB
>   stick:
>
> cd /Volumes/USB_STICK/ && cp -r ~/AHT_ARCHIVE/System .
>
> 4) Now, from the USB drive, copy the
>   /System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/diags.efi to the root
>   directory:
>
> cd /Volumes/USB_STICK/ && cp
>   ./System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/diags.efi .
>
> 5) Shutdown all applications.
>
> 6) “bless” the USB drive in mount-mode, with the EFI file, and
>   immediately reboot:
>
> cd /Volumes/USB_STICK/ && sudo bless --mount /Volumes/USB_STICK
>   --setBoot --file diags.efi && sudo reboot
>
> 7) You should now be booting into AHT -- don’t hold down any keys.
>
> 8) Run the tests, and yank the USB key after AHT reboots you.